# How to compare each value from two rows column by column and put the result in one cell in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have something like this

Row

```
1->   1   3   4   2   1   1

2->   2   1   3   4   2   2
```

I want to find how many values of row 1 are greater than the ones in row 2 and have them in a cell.

The result should be 2 since I want to only compare column A with A, B with B,  and *not* A with B, A with C, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula((A1:Z1>A2:Z2)*1))
```

and adjust end column reference to suit.

You could instead try `=sum(ArrayFormula((1:1>2:2)*1))` but would then limit use of the first two rows of columns AA onwards without risk of erroneous results.